# <a> tag with height: 100% and needs to have text centered vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, css-grid, vertical-alignment, centering

I have an anchor tag `<a>` and I display it under a list item tag under an unordered list (which is a navigation bar) using a grid (for a few different reasons).

This is the structure: `<ul><li><a>Content</a></li><li>...</li></ul>`

The ul is a grid display, with specific column widths etc. I style the list item `<li>` element to be 100% width, and 100% height. (to fill all of the allocated space in the grid), then I style the a tag to be 100% of the width, and 100% of the height (I need it to fill the entire container.

I also style the `<a>` tag with a `text-align: center;` which works great for the horizontal centering, but not for the vertical text centering.

So the problem that I have is that the `<a>` tag "Content" is aligned to the top of the container (instead of the middle) I've tried many attempts at centering the `<a>` tag but without success.

Note: `vertical-align: middle;` has no effect on this element because it has 100% of the height.

Here is an example:

```css
ul.nav{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
ul.nav li{
  float: left;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  background-color: #e4ffe4;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.nav li a{
  color: black;
  /*padding: 1vw 5px 1vw 5px;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.nav li a span.linkText{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.nav li:hover{
  background-color: #b4ffb4;
}
```

```html
<html><head></head>
<body>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Content</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Another</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Final</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
<html>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to keep the element's height 100% and center its text; if so I would much appreciate the help. If not I will work on a workaround for my use case.

Comment: For anyone that happens upon this closed question I finally found a "somewhat okay" work around. set the ```line-height: ##px;``` where ## is the height of the element so in the example provided ```line-height: 50px``` and you will get your text centered.

Comment: Turns out the best solution is to make the anchor element display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; and it works great! even with a tag 100% width and height.

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your css :

```
a {
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Ummm no. That will not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

use padding instead of height. I change some css code check below snippet

```css
ul.nav{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
ul.nav li{    
    float: left;
    background-color: #e4ffe4;
}
ul.nav li a{
      color: black;
    padding: 0.8rem 0.3rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.nav li a span.linkText{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.nav li:hover{
  background-color: #b4ffb4;
}
```

```html
<html><head></head>
<body>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Content</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Another</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Final</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: No this does not answer my original question... My elements need to take up 100% of the height you simply ignored this fact and went ahead to let them shrink down to center the text.